# In how many ways can $n$ toys be distributed to $n$ children so that exactly one child does not receive a toy?

Tags: combinatorics

$n$ toys are to be distributed amongst $n$ children. The total number of ways in which these toys can be distributed so that exactly one child gets no toy is equal to?

I tried it with the concept that if one child gets no toy, then we are left with $n$ toys to be distributed amongst $n-1$ children. But this does not help and the answer is not coming.

Please somebody,can you give the detailed explanation how to solve this sum. Thanks

Comment: One child gets no toy. Every other child gets a toy. There is one more toy left, give it to one child. Total ways: $n(n-1)$. The $n$ is to choose which child gets no toy. The $n-1$ is to choose which other child gets $2$ toys.

Comment: Thanks , but what will be the exact answer?

Comment: The exact answer is in Zach Teitler's comment.  It assumes the toys are identical.

Comment: But the answer guven is n!*nC2

Comment: That means the toys must be distinct, which should be stated in the problem.

Comment: That is a really mean way to distribute toys to children.

Answer (score 5):

The question is stated as follows:

> If $n$ $\color{red}{different}$ toys have to be distributed among $n$ children, then the total number of ways in which these toys can be distributed so that exactly one child gets no toy is equal to?

Source: [link](https://books.google.co.uz/books?id=IFseMd1nciMC&pg=SA11-PA31&lpg=SA11-PA31&dq=%22these%20toys%20can%20be%20distributed%22&source=bl&ots=rNbe0BcoCp&sig=mpMx4i6hv__NdBaxDOWbHid-6Yk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_3-ylqeXaAhXLAJoKHR-rDmIQ6AEIQDAF#v=onepage&q=%22these%20toys%20can%20be%20distributed%22&f=false)

Step 1: There are $n$ ways to choose the unlucky child.

Step 2: There are ${n\choose 2}$ ways to choose $2$ toys. Note: only 1 child can get maximum $2$ toys, otherwise more than $1$ child will get no toy.

Step 3: There are $n-1$ ways to choose the luckiest child, who will get the $2$ toys.

Step 4: There are $(n-2)!$ ways to distribute the rest $n-2$ toys to the rest $n-2$ children.

Hence:
$$n\cdot {n\choose 2}\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)!=n!{n\choose 2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the answer you provided in the comments, the toys must be distinct.  Therefore, we wish to count the number of ways $n$ different toys can be distributed to $n$ children if exactly one child does not receive a toy.

Strategy:

1. Choose which of the $n$ children receives no toy.
2. If the $n$ toys are distributed to the remaining $n - 1$ children, exactly one of those $n - 1$ children will receive two toys.  Choose that child.
3. Choose which two of the $n$ toys that child receives.
4. Give each of the remaining $n - 2$ children one of the remaining $n - 2$ toys.

Comment: Tausig's answer is correct. It can be simplified slightly as follows:  For 2, 3, and 4 substitute 2': Choose 2 of the $n$ toys and tie them together as if they were $1$ toy, creating $n-1$ newtoys, and 3' Distribute the $n-1$ newtoys to the remaining $n-1$ children.

Answer (score -2):

$1$ child gets $0$ toys, $(n-1)$ children get $1$ toy each, any of the $(n-1)$ children can get a $2$nd toy.

$1$ child can be left without a toy in $n$ ways. The 'extra' toy can be chosen in $n$ ways and so can be distributed among the remaining $(n-1)$ children in $n(n-1)$ ways. The remaining $(n-1)$ toys can be distributed among the remaining $(n-1)$ children (one toy each) in $(n-1)$! ways.

However, if the child getting $2$ toys gets toy $A$ as the 'extra' toy and toy $B$ as the 'ordinary' toy, this is the same as if this child gets toy B as the extra toy and toy $A$ as the ordinary toy. So we have counted $2\times$ as many combinations as we need.

So the number of distributions is
$$  \frac{n  n(n-1)(n-1)! }{ 2}
= n!  \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
= n! \frac{ n!}{2!(n-2)!}
= n!  C(n,2). $$

Comment: @Leucippus Why delete? [Wrong answers](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27423/290189) are to be downvoted instead of deleted.